# How to create a txt file with a user inputted name in python?

Tags: python

I have attached part of some python code that is designed to make 'decisions' based on user inputs. I currently cannot work out how to make the text file at the end (shown in the asterisks) have a name that is inputted by the user.

Also, sorry if this is worded confusingly- I am quite new to coding.

```
import csv

times = 1
Ops = []
print()  
genre = input("Genre: ")
num = input("How many " + str(genre) + "s do I have to choose from? ")
**text_file= open(genre.txt, "w+")**
  
while int(times) <= int(num):
    option = input("Option " + str(times) + ": ")
    Ops.append(option)
    text_file.write(option)
    times = times + 1
print()
```

How would go about doing this???

Comment: You've already used the `input` function, why don't you use it again to let the user input a name for a file?

Comment: ```text_file= open(genre.txt, "w+")``` should have `genre.txt` in quotes like `genre+".txt"` to get it to a string if I follow what you're trying to do

Comment: See answer.  Question written confusingly, but reading it the intent intended, I think I have provided an answer and useful learning information.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code and attempting to understand it -- I think I know what you are trying to do, so here is my attempt and suggestions.

1. Remove "import csv" (not necessary), maybe later, not now.
2. It looks like you are creating a file based on the input into the variable "genre", so in the open statement should be: `open(genre+".txt", "w+")`
3. Instead of asking how many different options you will be inputting and writing to the file, let that be dynamic, and provide a end-of-input designation that will stop accepting options and write everything to the file.

Suggested code:

```
options = list()
genre = input("Genre: ")
option = ""
count = 1
while option != "done":
   option = input("Option "+str(count)+": ")
   if option != "done":
      options.append(option)
      count += 1

with open(genre+'.txt', 'w+') as text_file:
  text_file.write("\n".join(options))
```

Explanations:
If using Python2, use raw_input() instead of input().

The while statement will continue to loop, accepting "options", and incrementing counter until you specify "done" by itself, which will not be included in the list of options, and the loop will end.

The "with" statement, tells python to execute everything indented under it with the context of the open file "text_file".

The ".join()" statement is an list operator that joins each element in the list with a "\n" which means "newline".  So with a list of ["rock", "classical", "pop"] it would write:  "rock\nclassical\npop\n" which when written to the file it will look like:

```
rock
classical
pop
```